# Wireguard specify listen address

Tags: linux, wireguard

Is there a way to configure the Linux wireguard module to only listen on a specific IP address for incoming connections instead of it's default of listening on all available addresses? I cannot find any documentation for this.

Comment: Only with a little help from nftables / iptables. Wireguard itself doesn't care.

Comment: From a cursory look it's not possible but you can limit connections using iptables/nftables.

Comment: …another option may be network namespaces.

Comment: Since the answer is "no", perhaps you could give more details to your specific use case so you'd receive answers on how to address your problem, despite not being able to bind the wg interface to a single IP address.

Comment: @A.B ehhh, no is the actual answer to this question. My specific use case is pretty irrelevant and here's why. I run a pure IPv6 network and my wireguard drives my OCD crazy by binding to BOTH 0.0.0.0:port and [::]:port...I wanted to stop it from listening on v4 since no v4 address is present on my system, since the answer is no that's the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WireGuard's Linux kernel module has no option to choose the IP address the interface will use for the tunnel.

In particuliar, following OP's [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/727166/wireguard-specify-listen-address?noredirect=1#comment1378706_727166) about wanting it not to bind with IPv4 but only IPv6, it will always use IPv4, as seen in the [external compat module](https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-linux-compat/tree/src/socket.c?h=v1.0.20220627#n349) or the [upstreamed module](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/wireguard/socket.c?h=v6.0.11#n349):

> ```
> int wg_socket_init(struct wg_device *wg, u16 port)
> {
> ```

> ```
>   struct socket *new4 = NULL, *new6 = NULL;
>   struct udp_port_cfg port4 = {
>       .family = AF_INET,
>       .local_ip.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY),
>       .local_udp_port = htons(port),
>       .use_udp_checksums = true
>   };
> #if IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_IPV6)
>   int retries = 0;
>   struct udp_port_cfg port6 = {
> ```

> ```
>   ret = udp_sock_create(net, &port4, &new4);
>   if (ret < 0) {
>       pr_err("%s: Could not create IPv4 socket\n", wg->dev->name);
>       goto out;
>   }
> ```

The IPv4 socket creation (as well as IPv6 when available) is mandatory, and is also always done using `INADDR_ANY`.

The code should probably have to be amended for multiple things to address the title of the question:

- select which protocol is used or disabled,
- select which address to use instead of `INADDR_ANY` and `IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT`/`&in6addr_any` (with possible interactions with previous bullet),
- and of course alter all parts of the code expecting differently.

Then for cross-OS compatibility with use cases, this would have to be also done to userspace variants of WireGuard, and other kernel (such as FreeBSD) variants.

---

Meanwhile for some use cases that would like to:

- allow the WireGuard tunnel envelope to be reachable only at a single address or single interface or single IP version (eg IPv6 only):

  Use a firewall to limit access to this address or interface or IP version/family only
- allow multiple different WireGuard interfaces to appear to use the same port on different interfaces

  Set them on different ports and use NAT rules (typically using both  DNAT in prerouting for initial ingress case plus SNAT in postrouting for initial egress case) to have the visible ports match the actual ports in use.
- avoid binding the UDP port on the host

  Hide WireGuard in its own namespace, at least at its initial creation, where the WireGuard port will stay. Then add an additional layer of routing (plus possibly NAT rules, but then it's almost the same as binding a port) to reach the tunnel envelope  (ie: this UDP port wherever it is), and if left in an other namespace, yet other additional layers of routing for the tunneled payload.